# My layout preview in android is showing different as compared to device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Please tell where my code is going wrong. Or it is problem with some settings. I have tried constraint layout also still it showing similar error. Also I have checked device resolution. It matches with preview but still it shows differently.

**This is the how it is showing in the preview.**
[image]

**This is how it is showing in device.**
[image]

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"


>

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/pr_image"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="144dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pr_image"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="124dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="125dp"
    android:text="@string/personal_details"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pr_name"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/full_name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pr_email"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pr_name"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed_location"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pr_email"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/location"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pd_links"
    android:layout_width="3000dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ed_location"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/links"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pd_mobile"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pd_links"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/mobile"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pd_save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pd_mobile"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="155dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
    android:text="@string/save" />
```

Comment: Try using constraint layout. a much better layout than relative layout

Answer (score 0):

Okay try this edited code of your xml file you were facing this problem because phone screen sizes differ and when you manually specify the width and run it into a particular phone will adjust itself as per the screen size and that's main reason your screen got messed up so instead of manually specifying the width set it as match_parent and provide left and right margins to solve your problem:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/pr_image"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="144dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pr_image"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="124dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="125dp"
    android:text="@string/personal_details"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pr_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/full_name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pr_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pr_name"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed_location"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pr_email"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/location"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pd_links"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ed_location"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/links"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pd_mobile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pd_links"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:hint="@string/mobile"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pd_save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pd_mobile"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="155dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
    android:text="@string/save" />
```

Comment: Please explain what are you doing so he can understand

Comment: If you're already using MarginLeft/Right and marginStart/End then set them on the same value. If the margin left is equal to margin right, then you don't need marginStart/End

Comment: @isaaaaame this answer is for his reference this is not a code writing service let him figure it out himself

Comment: @Mr. Patel  I tried your code but still, it is showing differently as comapred to preview it is showing.

Comment: @ShreyAgarwal remove start and end

Comment: upload one more screenshot of how layout looks like after change

Comment: Here the save button is going downward and "Personal Details is not expending to its width

Comment: personal details not expanding to it's width because in your string you must have specified \n remove that

Answer (score 0):

You are using fixed sizes on your views, and because different phones got different screen size this layout is not really responsive to all devices, if you want full responsive layout you better use [constraint layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).

If you want to use relative layout you better change your fixed sizes, but as already said constraint layout would be your best option - **here is an example of a simple layout that will look like you wished for :**

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars[5]" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Personal details"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Full name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Full Email"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Location"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Links"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:text="Mobile"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText5" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Full name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```